# How to do relation between some tables in one column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

I would to ask you how to do relation between some tables in one column?

- Tasks Table
- Customers Table
- Partners Table
- Competitors Table

Tasks table relation with (Customers, Partners and Competitors), and it have two columns (RelatedBy, WhoRelatedBy).

RelatedBy have list contain (Customers, Partners and Competitors)

WhoRelatedBy have value to determine ID of records as below:

- When select Customers in RelatedBy the WhoRelatedBy contain CustomerID
- When select Partners in RelatedBy the WhoRelatedBy contain PartnerID
- When select Competitors in RelatedBy the WhoRelatedBy contain CompetitorID

How do that?

Comment: Please add more info about what you have tried, what you got and what was expected

Answer (score 0):

The referential integrity relation on a database between two table is "static". 
When you create the relation it is always the same. All the id of the table(with CustomeId) must be contained in the other table that define the id.
You have as CustomerID that can contain an id that refer to three different column in three different table.
Than could not exist a referential integrity relation because an id could be exist in a table and not in an another table.

If you want absolutely a referential integrity relation, you must have three new table

```
TaskCustomer(IdTask, IdCustomer)
TaskPartners(IdTask, IdPartner) 
TaskCompetitors (IdTask, IdCompetitors)
```

this can have relation with task and customer because the IdTask in TaskCustomer for example will exist in Task.